# T-SQL using date format accounting the format of sql server

Tags: t-sql, date, format

I have the following query:

```
Select dateadd(HOUR, 24, '2018/10/15 00:00:00')
```

This works on my local SQL Server, but fails on SQL-Express due to the time format, which is the italian date format.
So I should write:

```
Select dateadd(HOUR, 24, '15/10/2018 00:00:00')
```

How to account for the difference in date format of the two servers.
I would like my query to run on both. Which syntax should I use?

Comment: You can force the locale for the current execution using SET LANGUAGE.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: That's not feasible for each query to do that?

Comment: Is there a way to know the dateformat of the server so that I know how to change my queries accordingly?

Comment: have a look at this:  https://database.guide/how-to-find-the-date-format-being-used-in-the-current-session-in-sql-server-t-sql/

Comment: Yes sir, use the SET LANGUAGE. You don't set it per query, you set it per connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using string literals as `date`, `time`, `datetime` or `datetime2` values, always use [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, since SQL Server will always convert it correctly to the appropriate data type.

- For date only, use `yyyy-mm-dd` (`2018-10-15`)
- For time only, use `hh:mm:ss` (24 hours) (`17:33:25`)
- For Date + time, use `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` again, (24 hours) (`2018-10-15T17:33:25`)

Comment: I have used the iso format, but it did not work on the other server

Comment: None of the string representations of dates in your question is ISO8601. The separators are meaningful as well. `2018/15/10` is not the same as `2018-15-10`.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. I'll try some more your solution

Comment: @PedroRodrigues SQL Does provide datetime types, but how do you instantiate a local variable with a datetime value? You can either use another datetime value, a built in method that returns a datetime value, or a string literal representing the datetime value.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you another approach, that may be helpful whenever your chances to standardize the input are limited: beside any specific culture on SQL Server, you can set a command-wide date format that applies only to subsequent commands, using `SET DATEFORMAT`.

Eg.

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd; 
Select dateadd(HOUR, 24, '2018/10/15 00:00:00')

SET DATEFORMAT dmy; 
Select dateadd(HOUR, 24, '15/10/2018 00:00:00')
```

You can use different formats by switching `y` (year), `m` (month) and `d` (day) characters.

Reference: [SET DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)